# Why sometimes, some images on my website aren't being loaded by a browser

Tags: performance, image, browser

I'm developing a web app and during the tests I noticed that sometimes browsers don't load all images (like background or some decorative images) on the website. I need to hit the refresh button to to have it fully loaded. This usually happens when the website is visited for the first time.

I suspect that maybe the development server is not fast enough and browsers "assume" that the links to images are broken because there is no fast response from the server. But I'm not sure. At the moment my development server is on a remote host inside VirtualBox with Ubuntu-server 8.04. I know that it is not the best configuration, but I'm not sure whether this is indeed the case. Or maybe it is due to some apache/php configuration parameters?

I would appreciate any suggestions or clues. 
Many thanks

Comment: Have you tried using Firebug or Fiddler to see what happens with the requests?

Comment: +1 to using an HTTP tracker--that's your best bet to finding out what's going on.

Comment: @Michael Todd. No, I haven't use Firebug for this particular problem, since I don't know what should I be looking at. Should I inspect HTML code, or does Firebug provides some sort of summary of all the requests, including requests for images? Also I haven't used Fiddler, since it seems to be only for Windows.

Comment: Firebug is a Firefox plugin that will give you a nice bar chart showing which images are being loaded and how long they take and (I think) whether the loads fail/time out.  Fiddler is an HTTP debugging proxy that does similar stuff for any browser.

Comment: Thanks. I found the bar in Firebug. I see that images that aren't loaded have Blocking time minus something (e.g. -123ms). Don't know what does it mean yet, but I'll look it up in the Internet. Hope it will help me.

Comment: Are these images (the not loaded ones) always the same?